# React router, detectar cuando no tiene parametro

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Estoy usando react-route para direccionar a este parámetros:

```
   <Router>
        <ul>
          <li> <Link to="/">Home</Link> </li>
          <li> <Link to="/politica">Política</Link> </li>
        </ul>

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/:id"  render={(props) => <SearchResults/>} />
      </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Y en mi componente este condicional:

```
    let { id } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
    
      if(id === ""){
        id = 0
      }
      onLoad(id);
    }, [id]);
```

Como puedo detectar que la ruta no tiene parámetro? con vacío ("") no funciona.

Traté también:

```
if(id === null)
```

Pero no reconoce la ruta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías modificar un poco tu código, de entrada en tu componente de routeo podrías indicar a la ruta que el parámetro no es un parámetro obligatorio, que es un parámetro opcional, esto se hace a partir de agregarle el símbolo "?" al parámetro, esto si estas usando la versión mas actualizada de react-route

Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/:id?"  render={(props) => <SearchResults/>} />
</Switch>
```

Dentro del código de tu ruta te recomiendo que al momento de desestructurar los parámetros utilices el parámetro id con un valor por default, quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
  let { id = 0 } = useParams();
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if(!id) console.log(id); // do something.
      onLoad(id);
    }, [id]);
```